# Error on my Emulator : An unhandled win32 exception occured in emulator?

Tags: android

I am getting this below error frequently, when I am running my android app on my emulator:

> "An unhandled win32 exception occured in emulator-arm.exe[4472]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled.In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just_In_Time"

Can any one of you solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Start the Android SDK Manager from start menu of your windows
2. In the SDK Manager, go to the "Virtual devices" page and click "New" to create a new device. Make sure you create a "Target" API that is within the range of the API's that your app supports. (Check Snapshot [recommend])
3. Once the Android Virtual Device (AVD) is created click "Start" to start it.
4. Wait until the AVD is fully started, then goto Eclipse
5. In Eclipse create a "Run configuration" for your app (if you do not have it already). In the run configuration make sure you select the device you've just created.
   Run your "run configuration". And be happy :)